# How to save a geometry and its material created in Three.js as collada file?

Tags: save, three.js, collada, exporter

I'm relatively new to programming and currently trying to learn more about three.js, a JavaScript 3D library. Many things are relatively easy to understand, but I an having a hard time saving an geometry and its material.

I have build a simple cube and an image is projected on to it whenever a picture is loaded.
like this:

```
$('#picture')[0].onload = function() {
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(this,null);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    cube.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
    render();
}
```

My goal is to save the cube and its material. Ideally I would like to save it directly as a .dae file since another program in which i would like to import my cube only takes .dae files.

However, i can not find a collada exporter for THREE.js. Therefore, I searched for other exporters which can produce a file format I can open in e.g. Blender or MeshLab and save as .dae from there. Unfortunately, I have not been able to save both geometry and material/picture with these exporters:

GeometryExporter.js, OBJExporter.js, SceneExporter.js

I also looked into the combination of OBJ and MTL. I did find the OBJMTLLoader.js, however I lack the knowledge to rewrite the OBJMTLLoader.js in to a OBJMTLExporter.js

Can anyone help me find a way to get from a cube and its (picture) material in THREE.js to a .dae file?

Answer (score 1):

For a very simple use case such as this, you could write the DAE manually, or even simpler, modify existing DAE on the fly. It's just XML if you change the file extension.

Create the simple cube with material in Blender, export it to DAE, and use it as a template. Simple DAE files are not very hard to read with text editor, you could find the relevant parts and just search & replace those parts in javascript (texture reference, material properties and UVs maybe).

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but could work. Not many formats have proper support for materials, and I doubt you have much success finding a working, fully featured Three.js exporter for such a thing (not sure though).